# Why does typescript infer Array in this conditional type?

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I have the following conditional type:

```js
type ComplexType<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends {
    type: unknown
    schema?: unknown
  }
    ?
        | (T[key]['schema'] extends object
            ? ComplexType<T[key]['schema']>
            : never)
        | TypeFromConstructor<T[key]['type']>
    : TypeFromConstructor<T[key]> | undefined
}

type TypeFromConstructor<T> = T extends StringConstructor
  ? string
  : T extends NumberConstructor
  ? number
  : T extends BooleanConstructor
  ? boolean
  : T extends DateConstructor
  ? Date
  : T extends ArrayConstructor
  ? never
  : T extends ObjectConstructor
  ? never
  : unknown
```

If I now use it on an object like this:

```js
const schema = {
  test: {
    type: Array,
    schema: [{
      type: Object,
      schema: {
        id: String,
      },
    }],
  },
}
type testType = ComplexType<typeof schema>
```

testType yields smth like: `{ test: Array<{id: string}> }`, but I would have expected smth like `{ test: { '0': {id: string}} }` because I never check if the type of `schema` is an array. I understand that iterating over the keys will also iterate over the array elements, but how can it infer it being an array, when the type does not check for it? And why does it not include the default array properties like length, etc into the type? Does it have smth to do with that an array is just an object in javascript?

Comment: It falls into this path twice: `T[key]['schema'] extends object` as the `Array<any> extends object` is true (`type DoesArrayExtedObject = Array<any> extends object ? true : false;` will be true). And the second time will be `[key in keyof T]` here `key` will be 0, then it will lookup for `TypeFromConstructor<T>`

Comment: @Eldar why does the type of `test` become an `Array`?

Comment: @Eldar As the comment above mentions, why does the type then stay an Array and not become an Object